# Clear SVG with forcegraph D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to clear my d3 force graph which I'm plotting to an SVG like this:

[image]

I try to clear my svg with:

```
graph["links"] = [];
      graph["nodes"] = [];
      queryWords = [];
      update();
```

but only the nodes are removed, the links stay being displayed, even with my force.links being empty:

[image]

Does anyone have a solution for this?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not empty under svg element?

Comment: you mean `svg.clear();`?

Comment: I mean like `svg.selectAll("g").remove();` (if you have all "g" elements under your svg of course)

Comment: `svg.selectAll("*").remove();` would clear everything and leave the `svg` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `remove/clear` using below ways:

```
d3.select("svg").remove();//Removes the whole svg
d3.selectAll("g").remove();//Removes the DOM and data of all g appended to svg
d3.select(".class").remove();//Removes any particular class attr added to svg or subelements.
d3.select("#id").remove();//Removes any particular id attr added to svg or subelements.
```